# Laravel variable not getting passed to route

Tags: php, laravel

In my page, I have the following anchor:

```html
<a href="{{ route('blogtitles.edit', $blogTitle) }}">Edit</a>
```

which links to the following function in the controller:

```php
public function edit(BlogTitle $blogTitle)
{
    return view('blogtitles.edit')->with('blogTitle', $blogTitle);
}
```

and then the `blogtitles/edit.blade.php` file simply contains:

```php
{{ $blogTitle }}
```

However, in the `edit.blade.php`, the variable '$blogTitle` is empty, even though I know that it isn't empty in the original page where it is passed from. Any idea at all what is going wrong? I have other anchors that do exactly the same thing and work fine, so no clue what the problem is.

The url to get to the `edit.blade.php` is
`http://localhost:8000/blogtitles/1/edit` and the routes are:

```
PUT|PATCH | blogtitles/{blogtitle}      | blogtitles.update  | App\Http\Controllers\BlogTitlesController@update                   | web                                                |
GET|HEAD  | blogtitles/{blogtitle}/edit | blogtitles.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\BlogTitlesController@edit                     | web
```

Comment: how is the edit Route::get is in routes/web.php?

Comment: @flakerimi `Route::resource('blogtitles', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogTitlesController');`

Comment: Yes, because resource use id, Do you have any blogtitle in database with id 1 that can be edited

Comment: @flakerimi yeah there is one on the database. Using id does not solve it, and my other anchor tags do not use id

Comment: can you try `<a href="{{ route('blogtitles.edit', ['blogTitle'=> $blogTitle]) }}">Edit</a>`

Comment: also Edit this post and add `php artisan routes` output

Comment: and last one to try : return view('blogtitles.edit', ['blogTitle'=> $blogTitle])

Comment: @flakerimi added the routes, and none of your suggestions worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238371/discussion-between-flakerimi-and-thomas-read).

Comment: you defined the route parameter as `blogtitle` not `blogTitle` so the var should be `$blogtitle` in the method signature for implicit route model binding

Comment: @lagbox ahh, I had to change `blogTitle` to `blogtitle` on the controller function. Strange, seeing as it was autogenerated by laravel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually in the function in the controller autogenerated by `php artisan`. The `$blogTitle` needed to be `$blogtitle` so the function became:

```php
public function edit(BlogTitle $blogtitle)
{
    return view('blogtitles.edit')->with('blogTitle', $blogtitle);
}
```

Thanks to user lagbox for prompting me to try this!

Comment: @lagbox thank you haha

Comment: np ... good luck, have fun and enjoy Laravel

Comment: You welcome. Are you using slugs?

Comment: @MaikLowrey nope

Answer (score 0):

you need to send only the id, like this

```
<a href="{{ route('blogtitles.edit', $blogTitle->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it - my others do it exactly the same way and work, no need to send the id